# LocalStorage updating inconsistently with setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After calling the refresh token endpoint to refresh the user's auth tokens, the local storage does not update the token field consistently. Sometimes, the local storage is updated properly and the app works well, other times the token and admin/student fields are deleted from local storage despite no error being logged and the endpoint returning a success response. How do I fix this? Code below

```js
import { parseTokens, parseAdmin, parseUser } from "../utils/auth-parser";
import { adminAuthFetch } from "../config/axios/axios-admin.config";
import { studentAuthFetch } from "../config/axios/axios-user.config";

export const refresher = async () => {
  const admin = parseAdmin();
  const student = parseUser();
  const token = parseTokens();

  if (!admin && !student) {
    return;
  }

  if (admin && !student) {
    console.log(
      "==========================refreshing token==================",
      new Date().getMilliseconds()
    );
    try {
      const response = await adminAuthFetch.post(`/auth/refresh-tokens`, {
        refresh_token: token.refresh,
      });

      const data = response?.data;
      console.log(data);

      localStorage.setItem(
        "tokens",
        JSON.stringify({
          access: data?.data?.auth_token,
          refresh: data?.data?.refresh_token,
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      localStorage.removeItem("tokens");
      localStorage.removeItem("admin");
    }
  } else if (student && !admin) {
    console.log(
      "==========================refreshing student token==================",
      new Date().getMilliseconds()
    );
    try {
      const response = await studentAuthFetch.post(`/auth/refresh-tokens`, {
        refresh_token: token.refresh,
      });

      const data = response?.data;
      console.log(data);

      localStorage.setItem(
        "tokens",
        JSON.stringify({
          access: data?.data?.auth_token,
          refresh: data?.data?.refresh_token,
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      localStorage.removeItem("tokens");
      localStorage.removeItem("student");
    }
  }
};
```

Here's the Effect that is called from the root app

```js
  const refreshFunction = () => {
    if (!refreshRef.current) {
      refreshRef.current = true;
      refresher();
    } else {
      refreshRef.current = false;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(refreshFunction, 1000 * 60 * 2);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);
```

Despite receiving a success response from the endpoint and ensuring refresher function is called only once with the useref check, the token field in the local storage doesn't update consistently. Sometimes the values are updated, sometimes they are deleted without an error being logged to the console. Tried removing strict mode but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Without being certain about how everything in your code works, it's possible that despite your best intentions, the refresher function is rendering twice.

Could you share more context around the React version you're using? If you're using version 17, try doing something like this:

```js
let log = console.log
```

at the top level of your code, and use it for logging instead. My working theory is that some form of console.log suppression is happening on a second render, which is why you're not getting the logs, even though the localStorage removeItem call is still executing.

Let me know the React version, and we can continue debugging.

Comment: Yeah, this might be happening. The browser does not log any errors however console ninja (a VsCode logging extension) logs an error which confuses the hell outta me. This app uses react v18.2

Comment: Aye I use Console Ninja too!

That's odd — console.log suppression was presumably reversed in React 18. Purely in the interests of debugging the issue, could you set up a useState and render the error directly in your UI? I sometimes use that when I don't trust the lifecycle of my app.

Something like:

const [debug, setDebug] = useState('');

Then inside of your `catch` blocks, do a `setDebug(JSON.stringify(error))`

And finally, pass the error into a component:

`<p>{debug}</p>`

This way we will eliminate the suspicion of the second console.log suppression.

LMK how it goes!

Comment: Console Ninja is pretty awesome! I've not been able to replicate the error for some time now, which is about par for the app. As soon as it occurs again I'll try this. Debugging these kind of inconsistent errors is mind numbing. Though if I remember console ninja's output correctly, the error is an AxiosError and the useEffect was called multiple times which would explain the Axios. Kinda wish I took a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the useEffect calling the interval, switching to Dan Abramov's [useInterval custom hook](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) fixed it